# Unable to resolve the error in IronPython script embedded in Spotfire

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

Hi i am new to python and spotfire. I am unable to resolve the below error.
**code**

```
import System
from System.IO import FileStream, FileMode
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import TablePlot
from  Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Export import DataWriterTypeIdentifiers
import clr
clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")
from System.Windows.Forms import SaveFileDialog  
SaveFile = SaveFileDialog()   #GETS THE FILE PATH FROM THE USER THROUGH A FILEDIALOG
SaveFile.Filter = "xls Format (*.xls)|*.xlsx|*.xls|*.xlsx"
SaveFile.ShowDialog()
saveFilename = SaveFile.FileName
print "saveFilename=", saveFilename
stream = FileStream(saveFilename, FileMode.Create) #Export Table data to the file
vizTable.As[TablePlot]().ExportData(DataWriterTypeIdentifiers.ExcelXlsxDataWriter, stream)
stream.Dispose()
```

When i run the above code i get the below error.

```
System.MissingMemberException: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ExportData'
```

The above code is used to export data to excel sheet using spotfire tool.
Please do suggest me what to do thanks

Comment: what's the `vizTable` in your code ? it looks like it is an empty object

Comment: vizTable.As[TablePlot]() this retrning a none object.

Answer (score 0):

vizTable is empty because in order to have Spotfire to get it populated/initialized

you have to add it as a parameter for a script - in my example below such parameter is called myVisual - after added it can be used in code

[image]